# writing sql code in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have information entered into a text box on an ASP.net 3.5 page. when i click the submit button i would like this information written to a sql server database.

Can someone please tell me what I need to do to accomplish this. The end-user should not see anything.

I am using visual web developer 2008. the event handling code is placed in a separate file using vb.

Thank you.

Comment: So you dont know how to communicate with the database or run CRUD operations on the DB?

Comment: Updated my answer for your specific data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *lots* of different ways to accomplish this: Dynamic Data, LinqToSQL, Typed data sets, Data Access Application Block, or another ORM.  My preferred method is direct sql, which would use code something like this:

```
Public Sub SaveAnswer(ByVal answer As String)
    Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO [table1] (ans) VALUES (@Answer)"

    Using cn As New SqlConnection(getConnectionString()), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand(sql)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Answer", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = answer

        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub

Private Function getConnectionString() As String
    ''//normally read from a config file for this

    Return "Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Database=testdb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
End Function
```

A few things to take from this sample:

- It properly closes the db connection, even if an exception is thrown, via the `Using` block
- Parameterized query to prevent sql injection
- `getConnectionString()` is private.  You should abstract out your data access to a separate class or assembly, and this is one way to start enforcing that.

Comment: Hi Joel,

I prefer the direct method as well. In the sub for the event handler for the submit button click-event can I go ahead and follow the example above??

I have a text box called answer, a database called testdb with the table that i want to input data into called table1. answer will be placed in the ans column. Please advise. I don't quite follow the connection string.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to handle it. I would start with a few ADO.NET (the library .NET uses to talk to databases) resources:

- [Modifying Data with ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254950(VS.80).aspx)
- [ADO.NET Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254950(VS.80).aspx)
- [Simple INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3btz0xwf(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: how do i set up the connection to the database?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're a beginner to ASP.NET.  Your best bet is to look up tutorials online for building database-driven ASP.NET applications.  To answer your question directly here would be rewriting better-written tutorials found elsewhere.

You should start with a few targeted Google searches for tutorials, such as [this one](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=ASP.NET+Tutorial+Database+ADO.NET&btnG=Search).

My advice would be to start with 2.0, not 3.5 -- even though it's an older version, newer versions build upon it, so you'll be learning fundamentals that are still useful in 3.5.

Comment: We all have to start somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

Need to look into LINQ to SQL or ADO.NET (lower level)

Answer (score 0):

dot net 3.5 has a LINQ feature integrated with it...
you need not write the sql code... it is SQL ORM which does the job for you

create a database (.mdb file)
then a dbml file (which is datacontext) drag and drop the tables you created in the databse into the dbml...

then u are ready to code...

if the dbml file name is master ...and the table name is table1 and has a column column1

then this is how you use it

```
dim db = new masterdatacontext()
dim c = new table1()
c.column1 = textbox1.text()
db.table1.insertonsubmit(c)
db.submitchanges()
```

thats it...