# 'Using' resource variable must have an explicit initialization vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, using

i am trying to use a basic command on a database table, following the instruction i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889795/writing-sql-code-in-vb-net).  This is my first time doing sql stuff, and i am having some issues getting the first line of my 'using' to compile.  Here is my code:

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM my_table"

Using cn As SqlConnection(getConnectionString()),cmd As New SqlCommand(sql)
    //Do Some Stuff
End Using
```

The error i get is this:

```
BC36011: 'Using' resource variable must have an explicit initialization.
```

I looked at the msdn reference, but cant seem to figure out what im doing wrong.  Im using vb .net 4.0.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Using cn As New SqlConnection(getConnectionString()), _
      cmd As New SqlCommand(sql)
    //Do Some Stuff
End Using
```

Comment: oh duh...forgot the first 'New' instance initializer.  Thanks, forgive my oversight.